# Spring: How to make a service conditional on the availability of a PlatformTransactionManager bean?

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, javabeans

I have a `FooService` that I would like to be available only when a `PlatformTransactionManager` is available.

If I define my service like this and no `PlatformTransactionManager` is available, then my application will fail to start:

```java
@Service
public class FooService {
  public FooService(final PlatformTransactionManager txManager) { ... }
  ...
}
```

I wanted to use `ConditionalOnBean`, which should only annotate auto configuration classes. I refactored my code like this:

```java
@Configuration
public class FooAutoConfiguration {
  @Bean
  @ConditionalOnBean(PlatformTransactionManager.class)
  public FooService fooService(final PlatformTransactionManager txManager) {
    return new FooService(txManager);
  }
}

public class FooService {
  public FooService(final BarBean bar) { ... }
  ...
}
```

I wrote the following test for `FooService`:

```java
@ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
@Import(FooAutoConfiguration.class)
public class FooServiceTest {
  @Autowired
  private FooService fooService;

  @Test
  public void test() {
    System.out.println("fooService = " + fooService);
  }
}
```

But I get the following exception when I try to run it:

```
org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'com.acme.FooServiceTest': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'fooService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type 'com.acme.FooService' available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate. Dependency annotations: {@org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)}

    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:596)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:90)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:374)
(...)
```

However, I know that a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean is available, because the test runs fine when I `@Autowire` a `PlatformTransactionManager` in my test instead of a `FooService`.

Interestingly, I also tried to replace `PlatformTransactionManager` with `WebClient.Builder`, and everything ends up working as it should. What is so special about `PlatformTransactionManager`?

How can I write `FooService` so that it will work when a `PlatformTransactionManager` bean is available, and not prevent applications where no such bean is available from starting?

Comment: Will it make a difference if you use `@ImportAutoConfiguration(FooAutoConfiguration.class)` instead of `@Import`?

Comment: That didn't help, unfortunately.

Comment: And if you remove the `@Import` and let `SpringExtension` scan the entire Spring Boot Application building the full context? It's hard to see what are you doing without package names :(

Comment: Sorry, I'm still new to Spring and it's hard for me to know what information can be useful when trying to find out what's happening. Removing the `@Import` doesn't help. How are the package names relevant to this problem? Here's a pastebin which shows the "Conditions evaluation report", where we see that my service is not available because the `PlatformTransactionManager` is not available (even though it is): https://pastebin.com/RNUgrdDF

Comment: Will it help if you annotate `FooAutoConfiguration` with `@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)`?

Comment: YES! That's amazing, thanks a lot. I remember trying it before, but I had a whole bunch of annotations everywhere, and they probably interfered. I have now lost 1 full day of work because of this. These dependency injection frameworks feel like a huge waste of time to me; it's basically throwing to the trash years of work in compiler research and development, reimplementing a new programming language and trying to make it look like another one. Anyway, thank you very much. Can you turn your comment in an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add [`@AutoConfigureOrder`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/autoconfigure/AutoConfigureOrder.html) annotation to ensure that your auto-configuration class is processed after the transaction manager bean is registered by Spring Boot:

```
@Configuration
@AutoConfigureOrder(Ordered.LOWEST_PRECEDENCE)
public class FooAutoConfiguration {

}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, while this works fine in the test that is present in the question, it doesn't work in another project that uses this as a library... Again, I can `@Autowire` a `PlatformTransactionManager` without any issue, but not a `FooService`. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Interestingly, here's a pastebin where it shows that Spring thinks that `PlatformTransactionManager` is both available and not available (look at line 418, 837, 1131 and 1932): https://pastebin.com/mf0nNSFp. I tried adding various incantations of `@AutoConfigureAfter`, but without success.